# Riot.js SSR (Server side rendering) how to init scripts afterwards render

Tags: server-side-rendering, riot.js

I have done a server render of an app. How to init server side rendered app after render happened?
e.g.:

```
require("@riotjs/ssr/register")();
const App = require("./app.riot").default;
const riotRender = require("@riotjs/ssr").default;

app.get('/app', function (req, res) {
    res.render('../apps/apps/t/base', {
        app: "some data"
    });
});
```

And the server side just has riot compiler connected.
I did not get from the docs on how it should be done. Init a Riot component does not seem to help me.
E.g. UI.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="/js/riot+compiler.min.js"></script>
</head>

<app>[Rendered HTML]</app>
```

Adding component and initialising it like with browser rendering did not help.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to "@hydrate" the component.
Use the lib alongside with @ssr rendering lib in riot.
There is a good example about it.
https://github.com/riot/examples/tree/gh-pages/ssr

Somehow docs on Server side rendering do not mention it broadly.
Hope it helps someone else.